# Create the session IDs based on time-difference in events for individual users

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

I need to **create the session Id**s for individual users **based on the time difference** in the events triggered by them. If the time difference between two events in more than 60 minutes then new session id for a particular users

| User | Event_Time | Session Id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2016-01-01 00:00:15 | 1 |
| A | 2016-01-01 00:00:17 | 1 |
| A | 2016-01-01 00:00:27 | 1 |
| B | 2016-01-01 00:00:27 | 1 |
| A | 2016-01-01 04:01:59 | 2 |
| B | 2016-01-01 22:00:27 | 2 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use approach from gaps and islands problem - create groups based on size of time difference with previous row (via `lag` window function):

```
-- sample data
WITH dataset (User, Event_Time) AS (
    VALUES ('A', timestamp '2016-01-01 00:00:15'),
        ('A', timestamp '2016-01-01 00:00:17'),
        ('A', timestamp '2016-01-01 00:00:27'),
        ('B', timestamp '2016-01-01 00:00:27'),
        ('A', timestamp '2016-01-01 04:01:59'),
        ('B', timestamp '2016-01-01 22:00:27')
) 

--query
SELECT user,
    event_time,
    -- use cumulative sum as session id for group
    1 + sum(if(date_diff('minute', lag, event_time) > 60, 1, 0)) over ( partition by user order by event_time ) as session_id
FROM (
        SELECT *,
            lag(event_time) over ( partition by user order by event_time ) lag -- previous row event_time
        FROM dataset
    )
```

Output:

| user | event_time | session_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2016-01-01 00:00:15.000 | 1 |
| A | 2016-01-01 00:00:17.000 | 1 |
| A | 2016-01-01 00:00:27.000 | 1 |
| A | 2016-01-01 04:01:59.000 | 2 |
| B | 2016-01-01 00:00:27.000 | 1 |
| B | 2016-01-01 22:00:27.000 | 2 |